# For loop not working with multiple document.write's

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a html `<table>` with a loop that makes the output automatically inside the the table, but for some reason it seems not be working inside my for loop.

> this should be the output of converting Celsius to Fahrenheit:

```
0 Celsius = 32.00 Fahrenheit
5 Celsius = 41.00 Fahrenheit
10 Celsius = 50.00 Fahrenheit
15 Celsius = 59.00 Fahrenheit
20 Celsius = 68.00 Fahrenheit
25 Celsius = 77.00 Fahrenheit
30 Celsius = 86.00 Fahrenheit
35 Celsius = 95.00 Fahrenheit
40 Celsius = 104.00 Fahrenheit
45 Celsius = 113.00 Fahrenheit
50 Celsius = 122.00 Fahrenheit
55 Celsius = 131.00 Fahrenheit
60 Celsius = 140.00 Fahrenheit
65 Celsius = 149.00 Fahrenheit
70 Celsius = 158.00 Fahrenheit
75 Celsius = 167.00 Fahrenheit
80 Celsius = 176.00 Fahrenheit
85 Celsius = 185.00 Fahrenheit
90 Celsius = 194.00 Fahrenheit
95 Celsius = 203.00 Fahrenheit
100 Celsius = 212.00 Fahrenheit
105 Celsius = 221.00 Fahrenheit
110 Celsius = 230.00 Fahrenheit
```

> this should be the output of converting Fahrenheit to Celsius:

```
30 Fahrenheit = -1.11 Celsius
40 Fahrenheit = 4.44 Celsius
50 Fahrenheit = 10.00 Celsius
60 Fahrenheit = 15.56 Celsius
70 Fahrenheit = 21.11 Celsius
80 Fahrenheit = 26.67 Celsius
90 Fahrenheit = 32.22 Celsius
100 Fahrenheit = 37.78 Celsius
110 Fahrenheit = 43.33 Celsius
120 Fahrenheit = 48.89 Celsius
130 Fahrenheit = 54.44 Celsius
140 Fahrenheit = 60.00 Celsius
150 Fahrenheit = 65.56 Celsius
160 Fahrenheit = 71.11 Celsius
170 Fahrenheit = 76.67 Celsius
180 Fahrenheit = 82.22 Celsius
190 Fahrenheit = 87.78 Celsius
200 Fahrenheit = 93.33 Celsius
210 Fahrenheit = 98.89 Celsius
220 Fahrenheit = 104.44 Celsius
230 Fahrenheit = 110.00 Celsius
```

> Here is the javascript code:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    function StartCelsiusCalculation() {

        var c = document.getElementById("celsius").value;
        var step = 0;
        var min = 0;
        var max = 0;
        var i = {};
        // Convert a temperature in Celsius to Fahrenheit.

        function celsius2fahrenheit(c) {
            var f = c * 1.8 + 32;
            return f;
        }

        function generateCelsius2FahrenheitHTMLTable( min, max, step) {
            for (var i = min; i <= max; i + step, c + step){
            var emitter = '<tr><td>'+c+'</td><td>'+celsius2fahrenheit(c)+'</td></tr></br><br>';
            return emitter;
            }
        }

        document.write('<p><table border:1><tr><th>celsius</th><th>fahrenheit</th></tr></p><br>')
        document.write(generateCelsius2FahrenheitHTMLTable(0, 110, 5));
        document.write('</br>');
        document.write('</table>')
        document.write('<p>')
    }

    //Here starts the form of calculating Fahrenheit to celsius.

    function StartFahrenheitCalculation() {

        var f = document.getElementById("fahrenheit").value;
        var step = 0;
        var min = 0;
        var max = 0;
        var i = {};

        function fahrenheit2celsius(f) {
            var c = (f - 32) / 1.8;
            return c;
        }

        function generateFahrenheit2CelsiusHTMLTable( min, max, step) {
            for (i = min; i <= max; i + step, f + step){
                var emitter = '<tr><td>'+f+'</td><td>'+fahrenheit2celsius(f)+'</td></tr></br><br>'
                return emitter;
            }
        }

        document.write('<table border:1><tr><th>fahrenheit</th><th>celsius</th></tr></p><br>')
        document.write(generateFahrenheit2CelsiusHTMLTable(30, 230, 10));
        document.write('</br>');
        document.write('</table>')
        document.write('</p>')
    }
```

> Here is the css code:

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

    body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background-color: #fff;
        font-size: 13px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #container {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

> Here is the html code:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Fahrenheit - Celsius</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <h2>Celsius to Fahrenheit and back.</h2>
                <p>
                <input type="text" id="celsius" value="wat is de celcius?"> <button onclick="StartCelsiusCalculation()">Calculate Celsius</button></p>
                <p>
                <input type="text" id="fahrenheit" value="wat is de fahrenheit?"> <button onclick="StartFahrenheitCalculation()">Calculate fahrenheit</button></p>
                <p>
                    <script src="js/fc_implementation.js"></script>
                </p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to use innerHTML. As soon as you use document.write after the page has loaded, the first one will wipe your page

Comment: what do you do with the input value?

Comment: Try walking through your code with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would change your code

1. do not use document.write after load. It will wipe page and script.
2. Move functions outside the main function since they are real member functions
3. concatenate the html and use innerHTML
4. you pass values to the functions and then immediately zero them - Either have them as vars in the function and do not pass them or do not have them as vars in the function and pass them. I removed them from the function here
5. parseInt the values from the fields
6. move the emitter outside the loop
7. remove illegal tags from the table such as `br` and `p` between tags

```js
function celsius2fahrenheit(c) {
  var f = c * 1.8 + 32;
  return f;
}

function fahrenheit2celsius(f) {
  var c = (f - 32) / 1.8;
  return c;
}

function generateCelsius2FahrenheitHTMLTable(min, max, step) {
  var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("celsius").value,10), emitter="";
  if (isNaN(c) || c=="") c=0;
  for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step, c += step) {
    emitter += '<tr><td>' + c + '</td><td>' + celsius2fahrenheit(c) + '</td></tr>';
  }
  return emitter;
}

function generateFahrenheit2CelsiusHTMLTable(min, max, step) {
  var f = parseInt(document.getElementById("fahrenheit").value,10), emitter="";
  if (isNaN(f) || f=="") c=0;
  for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step, f += step) {
    emitter += '<tr><td>' + f + '</td><td>' + fahrenheit2celsius(f) + '</td></tr>'
  }
  return emitter;
}



function StartCelsiusCalculation() {
  // Convert a temperature in Celsius to Fahrenheit.
  var html = "";
  html+='<table border:1><tr><th>celsius</th><th>fahrenheit</th></tr>';
  html+=generateCelsius2FahrenheitHTMLTable(0, 110, 5);
  html+='</table>';
  document.getElementById("resultF").innerHTML=html;
}


function StartFahrenheitCalculation() {
//Here starts the form of calculating Fahrenheit to celsius.
  var html = "";
  html+='<table border:1><tr><th>fahrenheit</th><th>celsius</th></tr>';
  html+=generateFahrenheit2CelsiusHTMLTable(30, 230, 10);
  html+='</table>';
  document.getElementById("resultC").innerHTML=html;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#container {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h2>Celsius to Fahrenheit and back.</h2>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="celsius" placeholder="wat is de celcius?" value="" />
    <button type="button" onclick="StartCelsiusCalculation()">Calculate Celsius</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="fahrenheit" placeholder="wat is de fahrenheit?" value="" />
    <button type="button" onclick="StartFahrenheitCalculation()">Calculate fahrenheit</button>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="resultC"></div>
<div id="resultF"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your for loop is not writing anything on the document. Besides, it returns on the first iteration. You should do :

```
for (...) {
    var emitter = ...;
    document.write(emitter); //no return here
}
```

And :

```
document.write('<table border:1><tr><th>fahrenheit</th><th>celsius</th></tr></p><br>')
//No document.write here
generateFahrenheit2CelsiusHTMLTable(30, 230, 10);
document.write('</br>');
document.write('</table>')
document.write('</p>')
```

Please note that the first `document.write` will wipe any already existing html. And thus, should only be used for testing purposes. If you want to keep original HTML, you should use `innerHTML` for the element where you want to insert the table into.

Comment: He should not use document.write at all